# Making the current page's title change colour in the nav bar

Tags: html, css, navbar, highlight

I'm trying to make the current page's title change colour in the navigation bar that I have at the top of my website. The navbar is built in html with:

```
<div class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html" class="active" >Home</a>
        <a href="indian.xml">Indian</a>
        <a href="italian.xml">Italian</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS that attempts to style it is:

```
.navbar{
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #F5861F;
width: 100%;
}
.navbar a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar a:active{
    color:#ffe7d1;
}
.navbar a:visited{
    color:#8b4e14;
}
.navbar a:hover{
    color:#874404;
    font-size:20px;
}
.navbar a:current{
    color:#ffe7d1;
}
```

The `.navbar a:current` is left there after I read that active may not do as I hope (I changed `class="active"` to `class="current"`) but this also doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should change/add class `active`/`current` on the current page's link/title via JS.

Comment: Use the class selector `.active` instead of the `pseudo-state` selector `:active`, `.navbar a.active {
    color:#ffe7d1;
}`

Comment: @Krusader Could you give an example of how that would be done? I don't know much JS at all.

Comment: Here is some raw example in order to display how it can be used https://jsfiddle.net/5wed3xhm/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a.active {color: red}
```

`a:active` is not representing a class but a selector for a pseudoclass of `<a>` element

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: I changed .navbar a:active{ color:#ffe7d1; } to .navbar a.active{ color:#ffe7d1; } and it made no difference, is there something else I'm missing? Thanks for your time btw.

Answer (score 0):

`:active` is where the mistake is.

Try this

```
.navbar a.active{
  color:#ffe7d1;
}
```

Comment: I changed 

.navbar a:active{
    color:#ffe7d1;
}

to 

.navbar a.active{
    color:#ffe7d1;
}

and it made no difference, is there something else I'm missing? Thanks for your time btw.

Comment: Tried it myself and worked well. If you have more CSS in your page, maybe another selector overrides this one.

Comment: AH! 

It's the .navbar a:visited{
 color:#8b4e14;
}

Part that's doing it. Is there a way I can make it so visited links will change colour but the current page will over ride that and change the colour still? @Benoit Gambier

Comment: Put your "active" selector after your "visited" one in your CSS so that it's read after.